# Binding to same port on different IP addresses

Tags: iis, ip, iis-7.5, port, iis-8

My situation is as follows:

```
One machine with 2 IP addresses: 10.10.20.7 and 10.10.20.17
Two applications that listen on port 9000 (each on it's own IP)
```

What I'd like to achieve is while one app is down, the other wont manage to connect. For an example, if the app that is bound to 10.10.20.7 is stopped, the machine will no longer listen on the specific port on this specific IP, hence no connection on 10.10.20.7 will be made successful.
This contradicts a bit the way IIS works with HTTP.sys to my knowledge. No matter what I add in netsh iplisten, this scenario seems impossible.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Are there different applications (one IIS and the other one something else) or two different sites within IIS? What should the second app do, if there first is stopped?

Answer (score 0):

If the machine have 2 IP then yes you can have same port open on the 2 separate IPs. But if you are trying to load balance so one takes over if the other goes offline then you need to use either some type of software load balancer or hardware load balancer.